# Django Model Bidirectional Many to Many Declaration?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have two models, article and publication, in which I declare a manytomany field within Article. However, I also want to have a reference from publication to articles as well. Is the best way to just declare another ManyToManyField, i.e. Articles = models.ManyToManyField('Article'), and if so, how do I make it so that it's linked to that linking table?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField('Publication')

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    articles = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the model in wrong way
correct way should be:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```